# The app ID myId cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, xcode, ionic-framework

I am currently deploying the application to the Android Play Store with the ionic framework.

Now we have added a platform to deploy the iPhone app.

However, if you select signing > team in xcode, the following error occurs.

[image]

So I change the widget "id" value in the config.xml and then xcode error is disappeared.

**issue is**

I have already launched the application on Android, So I am worried that It will be a separate application in the play store. when I update the android application. because of change id's value.

Will changing the id actually cause problems?

If there is a problem, can I resolve the xcode error without changing the id value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The problem is that the ID length is too long and the verification fails. I set the ID for iOS separately from the Android app ID. The way to split the ID for each platform is solved by the link below.

[How can i separate app id and version in ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975935/how-can-i-separate-app-id-and-version-in-ionic-framework)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to have your own custom package id in config.xml

- Example you have downloaded a starter app from ionic start ......
- Before you add any platform open config.xml and update the
  id="ionic.starter.io" to id="com.myapp" and save and close config.xml
- Now open terminal add platform ios/android
- run ionic build ios/android  open config.xml after platform is added
- You CAN now see your custom package name updated in config.xml and also in the /platforms/android/src/com/{appname}/MainActivity.java

PS: adding attribute `--id="com.package"` while downloading any starter does not update the id in config.xml in v2/v3+ automatically.

Comment: In conclusion, if I change id in config.xml, It will be recognized as a same application in the Play Store?

Comment: I replace id with ionic.starter.io, then I get an error that the name exists in xcode. (error is same with before)