# How can i separate app id and version in ionic framework

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I had launched an application on Android with the ionic framework.

And I will launch the app on iOS.

So I want to take iOS and android's id and version separately.

The top part of my config.xml is now shown below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="myappid" version="1.0.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>myappname</name>
```

Can I branch off this code separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `<widget>` tag in your `config.xml` file You can:

- use `android-packageName` property to set android id value
- use `id` property as default app id so this id will be used for iOS Platform
- use `ios-CFBundleIdentifier` property for ios code Version
- use `android-versionCode` property for android code version